# Design Pattern Suggestion for data synchronization

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, design-patterns

Need your suggestion for designing below system:
The requirement is, I have 4 App Server connected to 4 DB server. User can use any app server to access the same application hosted on 4 app servers. But the data updated by a user in one server should be instantly available to user accessing the same app from different App server.

Is there any design pattern exist for such kind of synchronization?

Comment: It's called mirroring or replication and should usually just be solved at the database level. What have you tried for yourself?

Comment: have some queries. 1. are these app servers behind load balancer? ideally it should be that way. 2. four DB servers are mirros?

Comment: @CodeCaster : Thank you for reply. But I was asked to find solution at application design level instead of database. Do you have any idea if any existing GoF pattern can be implemented for this problem?

Comment: @Jack 1.Yes, App servers are behind load balancer. 2.As the solution is looking at application design level, I am not very sure about db servers.

Comment: Ideally it should not be a responsibility of the application to handle this. All DBs handle this scenario pretty well and the responsibility should be delegated to DB server.

Comment: you may find this link useful http://serverfault.com/questions/58829/how-to-keep-multiple-read-write-db-servers-in-sync

Answer (score 0):

"I was asked to find solution at application design level instead of database" - in that case, the fact that there is are 4 DB servers behind is irrelevant.

Since it should be solved at application level, these app servers need to communicate through some media. As others have already said, a DB would be a sane choice, but your requirements preclude that.

Therefore, your app servers must be able to communicate among themselves and implement some consensus resolution protocol (e.g. [Paxos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_%28computer_science%29) is quite well known) to ensure that they all agree on what is the 'truth'

This is usually done at infrastructure level, and not in the app itself. I would suggest using some distributed cache (e.g. memcached or redis cluster - but the latter is not ready yet) but it depends on other requirements (durability, etc). Additionally, IMO this also falls under the definition of database in this context i.e. it is infrastructure level, not app level.

The requirement to 'find solution at application design level' seems rather synthetic and not driven by functional requirements or driven by unsound non-functional requirements, but I can be wrong. I could imagine this being driven by performance requirements, but this would easily degrade performance.

Comment: Yes. I agree. it would degreade the performance because there have 4 DB servers and this is an attempt to use it as if there is only one.

Comment: Okay, let me tell you a practical scenario, Say any Bank. It has more than 50 branches across the city. The Bank has app server and DB server configured Branch wise. But the requirement is, wherever I will access the Customer, the information displayed should be the latest one irrespective of what branch they are updated. How this kind of environment can be set up? Any suggestions?